# Which Java code generates Wide instruction

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, instruction-set, jvm-bytecode

I am creating a JVM and trying to understand the bytecode instructions. I am trying to write java code that when compiled generates a .class file with wide instruction. Which java code would generate that kind of extended instruction? I am a little bit lost with the wide behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the JVMspec says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.wide):

> The *wide* instruction modifies the behavior of another instruction. It takes one of two formats, depending on the instruction being modified. The first form of the *wide* instruction modifies one of the instructions *iload*, *fload*, *aload*, *lload*, *dload*, *istore*, *fstore*, *astore*, *lstore*, *dstore*, or *ret* […]. The second form applies only to the *iinc* instruction[…].

So, the `wide` instruction is used to encode instructions loading or storing variables with an index not addressable with a single `byte`, i.e. higher than 255, or an `iinc` instruction with either, a variable index or an int offset, not fitting into a byte.

For the former, we have to declare as many local variable to trigger the generation of a matching `wide` instruction, for the latter, just a large enough increment value would suffice:

```
class WideInstruction {
    public static void largeIncrement(int i) { i += 1000; }
    public static int largeVarIndex() {
        int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12, i13, i14, i15, i16, i17, i18,
        i19, i20, i21, i22, i23, i24, i25, i26, i27, i28, i29, i30, i31, i32, i33, i34, i35,
        i36, i37, i38, i39, i40, i41, i42, i43, i44, i45, i46, i47, i48, i49, i50, i51, i52,
        i53, i54, i55, i56, i57, i58, i59, i60, i61, i62, i63, i64, i65, i66, i67, i68, i69,
        i70, i71, i72, i73, i74, i75, i76, i77, i78, i79, i80, i81, i82, i83, i84, i85, i86,
        i87, i88, i89, i90, i91, i92, i93, i94, i95, i96, i97, i98, i99, j0, j1, j2, j3, j4,
        j5, j6, j7, j8, j9, j10, j11, j12, j13, j14, j15, j16, j17, j18, j19, j20, j21, j22,
        j23, j24, j25, j26, j27, j28, j29, j30, j31, j32, j33, j34, j35, j36, j37, j38, j39,
        j40, j41, j42, j43, j44, j45, j46, j47, j48, j49, j50, j51, j52, j53, j54, j55, j56,
        j57, j58, j59, j60, j61, j62, j63, j64, j65, j66, j67, j68, j69, j70, j71, j72, j73,
        j74, j75, j76, j77, j78, j79, j80, j81, j82, j83, j84, j85, j86, j87, j88, j89, j90,
        j91, j92, j93, j94, j95, j96, j97, j98, j99, k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9,
        k10, k11, k12, k13, k14, k15, k16, k17, k18, k19, k20, k21, k22, k23, k24, k25, k26,
        k27, k28, k29, k30, k31, k32, k33, k34, k35, k36, k37, k38, k39, k40, k41, k42, k43,
        k44, k45, k46, k47, k48, k49, k50, k51, k52, k53, k54, k55, k56, k57 = 42;

        return k57;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        decompile();
    }
    private static void decompile() {
        try {
        new ProcessBuilder(
                Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin", "javap").toString(),
                "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
                "-c", MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName())
                .inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        } catch(IOException | InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
    private WideInstruction() {}
}
```

Interestingly, `javap` doesn’t print `wide iinc` nor `wide iload` resp. `wide istore`, but rather, `iinc_w`, `iload_w`, and `istore_w`. But that just demonstrates that there is no “Java Bytecode Assembly Language” standard.

```
Compiled from "WideInstruction.java"
class WideInstruction {
  public static void largeIncrement(int);
    Code:
       0: iinc_w        0, 1000
       6: return

  public static int largeVarIndex();
    Code:
       0: bipush        42
       2: istore_w      256
       6: iload_w       256
      10: ireturn

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #1                  // Method decompile:()V
       3: return
}
```

Comment: I was struggling to understand that the index that was wide. I opened your code with jclasslib, and it works perfeclty all the wides are shown! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in case of load and store instructions, it’s the index, in case of `iinc`, it’s both, the index and the constant value.

Comment: On a side note, if you want Java bytecode disassembly, I'd strongly recommend using Krakatau. It doesn't hide or mangle stuff like javap does and the assembly format it uses maps very directly to the classfile format. https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was truggling days for understading wide instruction.